# SQL query grabbing first integer from varbinary field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a few columns, one is which is of type `VarBinary(MAX)`. This column is created in code and written out. I know exactly what type of columns each of them are but is there a way to convert each segment out of the `VarBinary` data?

The first is an integer which contains the size of the following string
what comes after the string is a DOUBLE

So:

```
10ABCDEFGHIJ etc.
```

Is there a way to grab the "10" in a straight up SQL query? Instead of pulling all the data into my code?

JF

Comment: Please provide an example, in hexadecimal, of the `VarBinary` field value.

Comment: This is a shortened version as I can't post the full one but there is a "length" then the "string data" 

6A0842696C6C79204A6F6E65732C31302F32332F3230313520383A32313A333120414D0942696C6C79204A6F6E65732C31302F32362F3230313520393A31353 ....

Comment: @marc_s I'm sorry you didn't like the way I worded my question.

Comment: Just trying to help make the question better and more approachable - and one of my pet peeves: relational tables have **rows** and **columns** - not records and fields ..... but that's just me ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a [SWAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_wild-ass_guess) at what you asked for, but probably don't want:

```
-- ASCII "10ABCDEFGHIJ" in hexadecimal.
declare @Sample as VarBinary(16) = 0x31304142434445464748494a;

select @Sample as Sample, Cast( @Sample as VarChar(16) ) as SampleVarChar,
  Cast( SubString( @Sample, 1, 2 ) as Char(2) ) as FirstTwoDigitsString,
  Cast( Cast( SubString( @Sample, 1, 2 ) as Char(2) ) as Int ) as FirstTwoDigitsInt;
```

Based on your comment which provides a fractional number of bytes of binary data:

```
declare @Sample as VarBinary(256) =
   0x6A0842696C6C79204A6F6E65732C31302F32332F3230313520383A32313A333120414D0942696C6C79204A6F6E65732C31302F32362F3230313520393A3135;

select @Sample as SampleVarBinary,
  Cast( @Sample as VarChar(16) ) as SampleVarChar,
  Cast( SubString( @Sample, 1, 1 ) as Char(1) ) as FirstByteChar,
  ASCII( Cast( SubString( @Sample, 1, 1 ) as Char(1) ) ) as FirstByteInt,
  Cast( 0x6A as Int ) as ByteValue;
```

---

With the additional hint that `0x6A08` should return a length of `2154' the answer is clearer. Extract the first two bytes as a 16-bit LSB word:

```
declare @Sample as VarBinary(256) = 0x6A0842696C6C79204A6F6E65732C31302F32332F3230313520383A32313A333120414D0942696C6C79204A6F6E65732C31302F32362F3230313520393A3135;

select @Sample as SampleVarBinary,
  Cast( @Sample as VarChar(16) ) as SampleVarChar,
  Cast( SubString( @Sample, 1, 2 ) as NChar(1) ) as FirstWordNChar,
  Unicode( @Sample ) as FirstWordInt,
  Cast( 0x086A as Int ) as WordValue;
```

Comment: Thank you much, this confirms the fact my data is definitely encrypted. The first characters should have come back to a integer with the string size.

Comment: If your example starting with `0x6A08` is 106 characters then the length isn't encoded, it's simply a byte value. If the length is actually 2154 bytes then the length is `0x086A`, i.e. a 16-bit word with the least-significant-byte (LSB) first. Without a useful example of input data and expected result you're still asking us to guess what you want. Note that the length typically doesn't include the length itself, so the `VarBinary` will be one (or two) bytes longer than the length specifies,

Comment: Ok, I don't know why I didn't think of looking at that before, the length of the actual string when I have it in code is indeed, 2154 bytes long which then means 16-bit word with LSB first. I do apologize for not being able to provide a full set of data. I can definitely work with this ! I understand it is not quite a definitely answer, but you helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to and from binary with CAST, assuming the byte order is the same.

eg

```
declare @buf varbinary(max) = cast(cast(10 as int) as binary(4)) +  cast('ABCDEFGHIJ' as binary(10))

select @buf, substring(@buf,1,4), cast(substring(@buf,1,4) as int)
```

Comment: David, ok this seems straight forward for sure, I'm starting to think it's getting encrypted somewhere:

`s = <string coming in such as "aaa bbbb, 10/25/2020">
Dim i16 As Int16
Dim ch As Char()
s = Trim(s)
i16 = Len(s)
bw.Write(i16)
ch = s
bw.Write(ch)`

then the Binarywriter (bw) is added to the binary field in the sql table

which then looks like this in stored data

**0x6A0842696C6C79204A6F6E65732C31302F32332F3230313520383A32313A333120414D0942696C6C79204A6F6E65732** shortened...

Answer (score 0):

My usecase was to find file preamble and even this works (searching for `.bzip` files):

```sql
select * from DataTable where cast(Data as char(3)) = 'BZh'
```